# Extract Same Customers Information with different Customer ID in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that I want to get the same (CompanyName, Address, City, State and Zip) with different IDNum using dplyr in R

```
Company Name |  Address               | City        |  State  |  Zip    |   IDNum
Kiah Auto    |  101 Smith Ave         | Smith       |  AZ     |  87788  |   1001
Kiah Auto    |  101 Smith Ave         | Smith       |  AZ     |  87788  |   1002
ABC Auto     |  89 Broadway Ave       | Broadway    |  NY     |  10112  |   9001
ABC Auto     |  89 Broadway Ave       | Broadway    |  NY     |  10112  |   9001
XYZ Auto     |  3A West 13th Street   | San         |  CA     |  90111  |   2321
XYZ Auto     |  3A West 13th Street   | San         |  CA     |  90111  |   2001
```

Below is the table I want to achieve.

```
Company Name |  Address               | City        |  State  |  Zip    |   ID
Kiah Auto    |  101 Smith Ave         | Smith       |  AZ     |  87788  |   1001
Kiah Auto    |  101 Smith Ave         | Smith       |  AZ     |  87788  |   1002
XYZ Auto     |  3A West 13th Street   | San         |  CA     |  90111  |   2321
XYZ Auto     |  3A West 13th Street   | San         |  CA     |  90111  |   2001
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Select groups that have more than 1 unique value of `IDNum` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Company.Name, Address, City, State, Zip) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(IDNum) > 1) %>%
  ungroup -> result

result
#  Company.Name Address             City  State   Zip IDNum
#  <chr>        <chr>               <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
#1 Kiah Auto    101 Smith Ave       Smith AZ    87788  1001
#2 Kiah Auto    101 Smith Ave       Smith AZ    87788  1002
#3 XYZ Auto     3A West 13th Street San   CA    90111  2321
#4 XYZ Auto     3A West 13th Street San   CA    90111  2001
```

Also in base R and `data.table`.

```
result <- subset(df, ave(IDNum, Company.Name, Address, City, State, Zip, 
                 FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1)


#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[uniqueN(IDNum) > 1], .(Company.Name, Address, City, State, Zip)]
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a reproducible format using `dput`.

```
df <- structure(list(Company.Name = c("Kiah Auto", "Kiah Auto", "ABC Auto", 
"ABC Auto", "XYZ Auto", "XYZ Auto"), Address = c("101 Smith Ave", 
"101 Smith Ave", "89 Broadway Ave", "89 Broadway Ave", "3A West 13th Street", 
"3A West 13th Street"), City = c("Smith", "Smith", "Broadway", 
"Broadway", "San", "San"), State = c("AZ", "AZ", "NY", "NY", 
"CA", "CA"), Zip = c(87788L, 87788L, 10112L, 10112L, 90111L, 
90111L), IDNum = c(1001L, 1002L, 9001L, 9001L, 2321L, 2001L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```